# Viewing Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop from Android over WiFi

Tags: wireless, android, 22.04, desktop-sharing

Given:

- a desktop with `Ubuntu 22.04`;
- a device with `Android` OS;
- WiFi network to which the desktop and the device are connected.

I need to share `Ubuntu` screen to `Android` over WiFi, thus, installed `bVNC` on Android. I tried to play with `Ubuntu Remote Desktop` and `bVNC` settings but without luck. Each time, `bVNC` shows a connection failed error.

So, my question is: how to share my Ubuntu desktop with Android over WiFi? I need it for viewing only (not controlling).

[image: Ubuntu Remote Desktop]
[image: Android bVNC]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the entire day of searching for a solution, I've found it. `Enable Legacy VNC Protocol` should be enabled. Then, copy and paste a `VNC Address` (just make sure to paste only the part after `vnc://`). Setup `Authentication` options as you wish.

**Note:** if it doesn't help, try rebooting the desktop.

[image: Ubuntu]
[image: Android]